# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources, Cannot create resource output directory: /app/target/classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

**org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project: Cannot create resource output directory: /app/target/classes
**

**This is the Trace
**
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:306)`
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)`
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)`
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)`
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)`
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)`
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)`
`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)`
`at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)`
`at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)`
`at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)`
`at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)`
`at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)`
`at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)`
`at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)`
`at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)`
`at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
`at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)`
`at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)`
`at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)`
`at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)`

I tried changing java and spring versions, but it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Can you explain this `/app/target/classes` is this really starting with root directory or is this based on removing things which should not being posted here?? ... Can you show the pom file ..and the rest of the logging output....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.